# What is the × (X) next to tags in tag list?

Tags: discussion, tags, design

On this page with the list of tags: https://stackoverflow.com/tags there is a × next to tags, but it is not clickable, and there is no tooltip.

What are these × used for?

[image: Screenshot of the tag with the ×]

Comment: It’s `<span class="item-multiplier-x">×</span>`. `multiplier` suggests that this tag is used this many times.

Comment: If you go to the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page instead and look at the related tags this is more clear, IMO the one on the tags page should be centered rather than positioned by the tag

Comment: Now you say it, it seems obvious. Or maybe the space between the × and the number is to high.

Comment: Could you state your browser version, OS version, and whether you're using stylesheet browser extension? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIOaB.png) is on Windows 10, Chrome 71, which I think the space between them (a single [non-breaking white space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)) is "close enough".

Comment: You should read this as _tag javascript [times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign) 1752705_ which implies that the tag has been used 1752705 _times_.

Comment: @AndrewT. Firefox Quantum 65.0 (64 bits) on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with Xfce 4.12

Comment: @kvantour "Used" how? In what manner? That could mean at least three different things.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The × refers to the number of questions using the tag. The example used in your post simply means that there are 1,752,705 posts with the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

Comment: In my opinion, this is clear enough without the "×". SO should remove it and just have a number. If some people get confused what the number means, the × won't help, and alt text will be what they will try anyway, instead of looking at that symbol. The × may even be more confusing. Do you agree?

Comment: There definitely should be alt text.

Comment: There absolutely should be both alt text and a title text. Basic accessibility!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, it's literally the times character. There's no need for `[alt]` text because it's not an image and it's already machine-readable (which is to say you can determine the meaning to present to the user automatically). The unfortunate part is that screen readers don't necessarily handle these characters well. _That_ issue should be addressed by screen readers, but since the rest of the information makes sense in context I don't really see the issue here...

Comment: ...I don't expect every user to understand all text, certainly. And you want to minimize confusion in the UI so that users don't have to think hard to understand what's going on, but in this case, selecting the text and entering into google should be adequate to educate those who aren't aware of what a multiplication sign looks like.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with @EthanK888, but I can't downvote their suggestion.

Comment: Rather than `alt`, you probably mean `title` or some form of tooltip? I agree it would help much more than the `multiplier` symbol

Comment: @MathieuVIALES Oh yes. I meant `title` as well. Sorry.

Comment: @zzzzBov The problem is not the multiplication glyph. The problem is that nobody knows intuitively what "<a tag> times <a number>" means. There should be a tooltip over the number that tells us it means questions, answers, votes, contributors, followers, what? Like it does everywhere else. Combined with the bad kerning this question is an example of that.

Comment: Well then it seems to me that the simple fix would be to add a suffix to the number: `[tag] x 12345 questions`. Also fixing the keming would be good too.

Comment: @zzzzBov like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aucpc.png

Comment: @astonearachnid, yep, and while we're at it lets fix the color contrast because [that grey isn't high enough contrast for WCAG AAA](https://contrast-ratio.com/#%236a737c-on-white).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you’re wrong here: virtually everybody *does* know what “‹thing› times ‹number›” and “‹thing› × ‹number›” means; it’s a firmly established idiom. The problem in this context is different: Namely, that other UI elements (on this site and elsewhere) condition readers to see the cross as a “close” button rather than the times symbol.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Once more, the main problem is not the glyph or the concept of multiplication. The problem is that it is completely impossible to determine with certainty what the number represents, and that the kerning does make the idiom a little hard to spot (if that weren't so, this question would not have been posted). But this comment simply duplicates the last one. Perhaps you missed it. Do you _really_ think it's "wrong" to have alt text and title text? _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_  Konrad these are _basic fundamental principles_ that web design has encouraged for many years. See all the other places that we have the "<tag> x <number>" idiom on Stack Overflow. Like, literally all of them! They get it right. It's just this particular instance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, having alt text for *text* is wrong, and it, or a title text, absolutely wouldn’t solve the problem here because it’s undiscoverable (and no, it’s absolutely not a fundamental principle of web design in this particular context for this reason).

Comment: @KonradRudolph What do you mean "undiscoverable"? The title attribute is commonly used for tooltips. Go to your profile and hover over the tag "counts"! They _all_ provide an explanatory breakdown. Why can't we / shouldn't we have that here? Though I'll agree about the alt text on reflection as that's for non-text things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It’s undiscoverable because there’s no indication whatsoever that hovering would reveal information. It’s completely hidden and non-obvious. It therefore wouldn’t solve the problem at all. Even the hover of the tags themselves is pretty undiscoverable, but hovering over an interactive button-thingy is a lot more obvious than hovering over a cross in text. A much better solution is to fix the (wrong) typography: remove or reduce the space between times and number, fix the (currently wrong) font size and colour.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Again yes the kerning needs to be fixed. But I can't possibly agree that tooltips are "undiscoverable". They are common UI practice. Who doesn't know about tooltips? Guess we'll have to agree to disagree!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Tooltips on non-interactive elements aren’t common UI practice *at all*, except in special circumstances (such as the comment dates) and *even there* they are unarguably a hidden feature, and the vast, *vast* majority of users has no idea about their existence. In fact, to indicate that an element has a tooltip it’s best practice to indicate this via markup (e.g. dotted underline) as well as cursor changes (and Stack Overflow fails in both regards in their use of tooltips).